# How to find area of given coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

How to find area of given coordinates?
Requirements:
 I have a polygon coordinates on a map then we want to find area of polygon in hectares and acres

Coordinates are in decimal degrees area should be in decimal degrees
we can convert hectares and acres kindly replay me

Coordinates are

```
(10.072642780669105,76.3268655538559),(10.078051232146612,76.32986962795258]),(10.073530110959743,76.33390367031097)
```

Code

```
    arr=[ [10.075854059674523, 76.32832467556], 
          [10.079825860518895, 76.33338868618011], 
          [10.076234340596953, 76.33806645870209], 
          [10.07065684212598, 76.33806645870209],
          [10.068924417668397, 76.33175790309906] ]; 
    var sum=0; 
    for(var i=0,l=arr.length-1;i<l;i++){ sum+=(arr[i][0]*arr[i+1][1]-arr[i+1][0]*arr[i][1]); }
 alert('The Area of Ploygon is:'+(sum/2));
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math

Comment: It depends on the radius of the sphere.

Comment: Maybe not off topic if there is a JavaScript library for that? It is true that if this is what the user wants, it should be indicated in the question, though.

Comment: @Paul the radius seems to be the Earth radius (aprox 6.370.000 meters)

Comment: coordinates willbe taken in decimal degree

Comment: And hectares is an Earth measurement, I believe related to meter^2.  Now if there were only a way to go from decimal degrees to an arc on a great circle that is actually almost a leg of a flat rectangle, I could eat some pie.

Comment: Would some else like pie?  There are 2 pie.

Comment: I agree with @Wooble on the off-topicality of this question.  If OP had a mathematical solution to the problem then assisting her in writing the code to implement it would be on-topic.  Since OP has only tagged this as `math` it's difficult to construe it as a programming question.

Comment: Actually google searches for "decimal degrees to hectares" also provide enough to solve it.  I'd go along with a vote to close.

Comment: Actually I plot a region on a map using Leaflet that will got coordinates then we can analyze area for that region

area should be in hectares and acres.

Comment: If you know the length of three sides of a triangle, you can use Heron's formula to find the area.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula .  If you use meters, then a hectare is 10000 m^2 . Google "acre to square meters" for acre.

Comment: area should be in which unit?

Comment: I have got a codevar arr=[
    [10.075854059674523, 76.32832467556],
    [10.079825860518895, 76.33338868618011],
    [10.076234340596953, 76.33806645870209],
    [10.07065684212598, 76.33806645870209],
    [10.068924417668397, 76.33175790309906]
];
var sum=0;
for(var i=0,l=arr.length-1;i<l;i++){
    sum+=(arr[i][0]*arr[i+1][1]-arr[i+1][0]*arr[i][1]);
}
alert('The Area of Ploygon is:'+(sum/2)); but this area should be in which unit?

Comment: Guys please don't down vote question only for reason that you don't understand it.

Comment: Actually coordinates are in decimal degree but area has which unit?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about GIS.  Ask on gis.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite complex and is not exactly math.
If you want to get real world result not some math theory you have to notice that earth is not sphere - look for WGS 84 in Google.

One of algorithms that can be implemented quite fast is Montecarlo:

Find the minimum bounding box of polygon (for small areas you can handle earth as flat surface)

Calculate area of MBB as for rectangle S = a*b

Get N random points inside the rectangle

Find M =  points inside the polygon

Surface of your polygon is S*M/N

Increasing N gives you higher accuracy.

You should easy find algorithms for resolving each step (finding distance from one geo point to other geo point, checking if point x/y is inside of figure)

Comment: Erm, did you intend to give a formula for M at some point? And to describe how to convert the spherical coordinates into a planar polygon?

Answer (score 0):

The polygon area code compares favorably with [another math site where the problem is explained under 2-D polygons](http://geomalgorithms.com/a01-_area.html).

The problem is you have squared degrees.

Well, for small patches of land the Earth can be considered flat, and for converting squared degrees to hectares or acres or square meters you need to know how long a degree is.

At the Equator, a degree on Earth is 1/360th of the circumference of Earth which is 2*Pi*Rearth or ~40000km.

1 degree is approximately 1/360th of 40000 km = approximately 111 km per degree.

1km is 1000m.  1 km^2 = 10^6 m^2.  But 1 hectrare = 10000 m^2, so 1km^2 is 100 hectares.

A squared degree will be approximately (111^2 km^2) (100 hectares/km^2) ~=  1232100 hectares

Ah, but I cheated, this only works near the Equator.

The Earth is a little bit fatter than 40000 km around, and also a degree of longitude becomes shorter as you get near the pole. Degrees of latitude N or S are always 1/360th of the way around the Earth from pole to pole, but degrees of longitude are widest at the equator and become narrower as `cos(latitude)`.

Comment: In google we can identified :calculated_acres = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea(points_array)/(1000*1000)*247.105381);

Comment: that will be use in leaflet please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need a library to do the conversion for you.

It actually depends on where you are in the world and how precise you want to be.  Bear in mind that land is neither flat nor necessarily aligned with the underlying sphereoid.

The company I work for sprays bracken from the air and produces maps of where the spraying occurred plotted on Ordnance survey maps accurate to a metre or two.

In the UK you may find these useful, they detail the complexity of these conversions which I'm not even going to try to summarise here.

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/navigation-technology/os-net/surveying.html

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/support/guide-coordinate-systems-great-britain.pdf

It appears the Ordnance Survey don't have the old conversion paper that I learned from on their site but I found a copy here.
http://www.fgg.uni-lj.si/~/mkuhar/Zalozba/TM_projection.pdf